# ALTER TABLE <table> REBUILD error

Tags: oracle10g, compiler-errors

When i execute this sql command:

```
alter table <table> rebuild;
```

i have this error:

[image]

i use:

> Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bi
>   PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

Thx

Comment: I guess you want to build an index in which case it would be `alter index <index_name> rebuild;`

Comment: i can rebuild index for a table ?

Comment: how to know all the How do I know the names of my index to my table?

Comment: @Mercer- Use `select index_name from user_indexes where table_name='your_table_name'`